# Sending data to a deeply nested angular component

Tags: angular

I have a components hierarchy, like A contains B, B contains C and C contains D.

I need to send some data from top most component(A) to one at bottom of the hierarchy(D).

Do I need to do data binding in html templates, which then I would need to do all levels?

Or is there a way to directly communicate data from A to D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For data and storage manipulation in complex applications with deep nesting you have two general ways:

- Service (‘ng g s’) where you use singleton service class to store and provide data everywhere yoy need it.
- State storage solution like Redux or Flux where you receive centealized storage for the app data and provide unified ways to receive and manipulate it.

Data binding works only to simple cases.

Comment: Hi @pesho34, Since I am not aware of these ways, can you provide a link where  I can study more about this.

Comment: @AdritaSharma [You can read more about communicating between components here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: @StepUp I am aware of all 4 of these.  I wanted to know about State storage solution like Redux or Flux  from pesho34

Comment: @AdritaSharma [You can read about Redux here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-with-redux-using-ngrx-store-2f93a8ad0dd)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which can share data between components:

**YourDataService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class YourDataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('Foo message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

**one.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YourDataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: YourDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }    
}
```

**two.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YourDataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `
})
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: YourDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }
}
```

**Or using** `@Input`:

**one.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'one',
  template: `
    <two [childMessage]="parentMessage"></two>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class OneComponent{
  parentMessage = "message from One"
  constructor() { }
}
```

**two.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'two',
  template: `
      It is a new message from one: {{ message }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class TwoComponent {

  @Input() childMessage: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `extend` properties from A like this:

```
class A {
    sayHello() {
        console.log('hello');
    }

    walk() {
        console.log('I am walking!');
    }
 }

class B extends A {}

const BComponent = new B();
BComponent.sayHello();
BComponent.walk();
```

And you will get access to methods A from B, this is solution with pure JavaScript, but the idea is the same, you just need to `extend` from class